# How can I prevent users capture the video screen in my website?

Tags: web, encryption, video-capture

I found that Netfilx can prevent users from screen capturing on their videos. If you do screen capture on their videos, you will get black screen.

How does it work? What technique is involved in?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually functionality provided by the DRM systems and the devices or browsers secure media path.

You may find that certain browsers support this and other don't, depending on where the combination of device, browser or player and DRM system supports it.

It is an evolving story and those that don't currently support it typically will have plans to add support.

Comment: Where can I find the tutorial of DRM systems? I have searched for DRM systems on the internet but a lot of articles is just about the concept of DRM. There is no any practical coding example or tutorial.

Comment: What if the user runs a virtual machine and the host captures the screen? This is cat and mouse game. As long as user has the root access, there is no real solution.

Comment: Yes it is a bit cat and mouse - most security is like this. Virtual machines and root access etc is usually handled - i.e. it is 'cat and mouse history' by now, but new attacks and new preventative measures will continue to emerge. Some good info here on how to use DRM: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/playready/

Comment: @Mick but your link just mentioned how it works. There is no any tutorial to teach us how to implement DRM from scratch.